# Download compressed derivative

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

We are using SQLite properties database to get properties information for the translated model. SQLite database file is usually several times bigger than the initial Revit file and it takes a long time to download it.
Is it possible to set some undocumented query parameter to download a compressed version of the database file? gzip version of database file should be significantly smaller than the uncompressed version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this endpoint does not support the 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' header to get the compressed version. I reported the issue to the engineering team to get it implemented.

In the meantime, you could download the file by chunks in parallel. Running multiple threads will accelerate the download time. I know it is more complex and does not really address your issue, but that is the only workaround I got at this time.

Comment: Thanks, Cyrille! Actually, we tried to download the file by chunks, but got some error. We will try again, maybe we have done something wrong

Comment: Ok, let me know if you still have issue with chunks, and I give you an example